# substituting images in simple javascript animation

Tags: javascript, image, animation, src

I'm hoping for a bit of help with this please.

I've got four animated gifs on a page, moving randomly.

```
<div class="backgroundWrapper">
    <img id="bee1" class="hidden-xs bee clockBee1" src="https://purl.co.nz/testRecipientID_Test/img/clockBee1.gif">
    <img id="bee2" class="hidden-xs bee clockBee2" src="https://purl.co.nz/testRecipientID_Test/img/clockBee1.gif">
    <img id="bee3" class="hidden-xs bee clockBee3" src="https://purl.co.nz/testRecipientID_Test/img/clockBee3.gif">
    <img id="bee4" class="hidden-xs bee clockBee4" src="https://purl.co.nz/testRecipientID_Test/img/clockBee3.gif">
</div>
```

When the gif is moving from left to right I want it to be the default version, but when it moves from left to right I want to substitute another gif that points the other way.

```
var bees=document.getElementsByClassName("bee");

for(var i=0;i<bees.length;i++){
    animateDiv(bees[i]);
}


function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(theBee){
    theImage=$(theBee).attr("src");
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $(theBee).offset();
    if(newq[1]<oldq.left){
        newImage=reverseImage(theImage);
        $(theBee).attr("src,newImage");
    }else{
        newImage=revertImage(theImage);
        $(theBee).attr("src,newImage");
    }
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $(theBee).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
    animateDiv(theBee);        



    });

}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}

function reverseImage(imgSource){
    var newImage="";
    if(imgSource=="img/clockBee1.gif"){
        newImage="img/clockBee1Reversed.gif";
    }
    else if(imgSource=="img/clockBee3.gif"){
        newImage="img/clockBee3Reversed.gif";
    }
    return newImage;
}
function revertImage(imgSource){
    var newImage="";
    if(imgSource=="img/clockBee1Reversed.gif"){
        newImage="img/clockBee1.gif";
    }
    else if(imgSource=="img/clockBee3Reversed.gif"){
        newImage="img/clockBee3.gif";
    }
        return newImage;
}
```

Please look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malcolmwhild/9sLmbbzk/19/). I hope I've done it right because it's the first time I've used JSFiddle.

Lines 25 to 31 are what is giving me the problem. When I inspect the page in Chrome (can you also do that in JSFiddle?), I can see the position values changing, but the src always stays the same. Lines 58-77 contain the (ugly) substitution code.

I hope that's enough information. Please ask if not.

Thanks in advance,

Malcolm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 problems in your code:

1. You are not using the Jquery `attr` correctly ( the correct syntax is `$( "selector" ).attr( "attribute", "new value"  )` notice that the comma is not within the `""`;
2. In  revertImage and reverseImage, you are using `if(imgSource==="img/clockBee1Reversed.gif")` to check the image path which is incorrect since the path will be something like: `https://purl.co.nz/testRecipientID_Test/img/clockBee1.gif`

A better approach is to avoid checking the path and just check whether the path has the word Reversed or not in it.The updated code looks like this:

```
  function reverseImage(imgSource){
if(imgSource.indexOf('Reversed')!==-1)// if the image is already reversed we don't do anything we just return the original path
   return imgSource;
    var newImage="";
    /*we remove the .gif from the image source*/
    var basePath=imgSource.slice(0,-4)
   /*we add the Reversed.gif to the image source*/
    newImage=basePath+'Reversed.gif'
    return newImage;
}
function revertImage(imgSource){
  // if the image is not reversed we don't do anything we just return the original path
  if(imgSource.indexOf('Reversed')===-1)
return imgSource;
    var newImage="";   
    /*we add the Reversed.gif from the image source*/
    var basePath=imgSource.slice(0,-12)
    /*we add the .gif to the image source*/
    newImage=basePath+'.gif'
    return newImage;
}
```

Here is a working version of your code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sLmbbzk/71/)

By the way, the `revertImage` and the `reverseImage` can be combined into a single function with some code modification. 
(for your information JSFIddle displays the javascript errors :) )

Comment: Thanks so much for your help radtelbi! I've updated my fiddle (don't know how to put it into a link in a comment) and it works fine. I'm interested in your test for the image - I would have used `if(condition==true)` - I wouldn't have thought of `if(condition!==-1)`. Why aren't they the same?

Comment: @MalcolmWhild `imgSource.indexOf('Reversed')` returns a number (the first occurrence of the string reversed in the imgSource more infos on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf  
 ) so my test will be for example  `if(3 === -1)` which is valid since I am simply comparing two numbers. I updated the link for JSFiddle it is working now

Comment: Perfect! and yes of course, we're not checking if a condition is true. Thanks for the link to the documentation as well - I'm guilty of trying to jump in and do something without reading up first ...